# Calling NSWindow with JNI

Tags: java, swift, macos, java-native-interface

I tried call Swift function from Java using JNI. My Swift function creates NSWindow with some content, and it's work, but when I call it from Java I get the next message:
*"NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future"* and my app crashes

**My swift function:**

```
@_silgen_name("swiftHelloWorld")
public func swiftHelloWorld() {
    let delegate = AppDelegate()
    let application = NSApplication.shared
    application.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
    application.delegate = delegate
    application.run()
}
```

**My Java code:**

```
public class SwiftHelloWorld {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SwiftHelloWorld");
    }

    public static native void printHelloWorldImpl();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        printHelloWorldImpl();
    }
}
```

**My C code:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld.h"
#include "helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld_swift.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld_printHelloWorldImpl (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    swiftHelloWorld();
    printf("%s", "Hello World from JNI!");
}
```

**Swift header:**

```
void swiftHelloWorld();
```

Comment: This is interesting! Honestly I'm not really sure *precisely* what defines which thread is the "main" thread. Perhaps that's worth looking into, so you know how to run this from your JNI code

Comment: Cocoa functions can indeed only be used in the "main" thread, which is the one that was created first at program startup. That's a know limitation. The macOS Java launcher starts Java on a second thread to keep the main thread free for UI operations. It has an option -XstartOnMainThread to override that behavior. The downside is that AWT will not work if you do that. Your only other option is to switch threads before execution your Cocoa function and synchronize somehow.

Comment: @user2543253 How does AppKit code “know” which thread is the first one started on program startup, if it wasn’t there to configure itself to “know” that? Does a library like P threads “privilege” one thread as the main thread?

Comment: I don't know the exact details. The main thread is the one that runs the "main" method. Should be easy to detect. Or just as easy to assign some flag to the thread as soon as the program starts.

Comment: I've just checked my code. I'm using `CFRunLoopGetMain()` to get the main run loop. Maybe you can go on from there.